# Error; al mostrar link de la base de datos de firebase en webview --- Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type ----

Tags: android, firebase

el objetivo que tengo es el de leer el url de la base de datos que tengo en firebase y que este url se muestre en una webview.

para empezar la apliclacion es tipo un blog donde se abre y aparacen las diferentes publicaciones
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces cada uno se genera a traves de la database de firebase, esta es la estructura de la database que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces cada vez que vaya ingresando una nueva publicacion se generara un link diferente entonces al hacer click en cada noticia dentro de la aplicacion va a la actividad donde esta el webview lo que me resulta dificil es que muestre el link correspodiente de la publicacion a la que le di click.

este es el error que me sale en android studio

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.leerfirebase, PID: 16938
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.leerfirebase.modelos.noticia
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:418)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:214)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:178)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:101)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:239)
        at com.example.leerfirebase.Activities.Brochures$1.onDataChange(Brochures.java:49)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Application terminated.
```

esta es mi actividad donde se encuentra el webview y quiero que lea el link del database de firebase

```
package com.example.leerfirebase.Activities;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.leerfirebase.R;
import com.example.leerfirebase.modelos.noticia;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.GenericTypeIndicator;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Brochures extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView msg_url;
    private WebView web_view;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    private DatabaseReference childReference = databaseReference.child("url");



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brochures);

        msg_url =findViewById(R.id.weburl);
        web_view = findViewById(R.id.brochures);
        web_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web_view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        childReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                GenericTypeIndicator<noticia> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<noticia>() {};
                 String resultado = dataSnapshot.getValue(t).getLink();


                //String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                msg_url.setText(resultado);
                web_view.loadUrl(resultado);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

ahora para esto tengo el modelo que me ayuda a clasificar los datos de la database de firebase

```
package com.example.leerfirebase.modelos;

public class noticia {

    private String postKey;
    private String titulo;
    private String descripcion;
    private String imagen;
    private String usuario;
    private String link;


    public noticia (String titulo, String descripcion, String imagen, String usuario,String link) {

        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.imagen = imagen;
        this.link = link;
        this.usuario = usuario;


    }
    public noticia(){

    }

    public noticia(String toString, String toString1, String imageDownlaodLink, String toString2) {
    }

    public String getPostKey() {
        return postKey;
    }

    public void setPostKey(String postKey) {
        this.postKey = postKey;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }

    public void setImagen(String imagen) {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

}
```

quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de poder realizar lo que les explique anteriormente, porfavor si pudieran ayudarme a resolver este error se los agradeceria.(si necesitan mas datos no duden en pedirmelo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa lo siguiente, no uses el `GenericType`

```
Noticia noticia = dataSnapshot.getValue(Noticia.class);
String link = noticia.getLink();
```

Recorda que el nombre de las clases es en mayusculas, asi que cambia el nombre de noticia a Noticia